# How can every single line of clipboard, if available, be opened as url in the same window, but delayed, in individual tabs with AutoHotkey (Chrome)?

Tags: regex, url, macros, autohotkey, clipboard

I want a multiple search in Google Images. I know that there is something like

```
clipboard := StrReplace(clipboard, "+", "%2B")
```

but how is it possible? Below is a code relating to the one-time search.

```
url_encoding(str)
{
  f = %A_FormatInteger%
  SetFormat, Integer, Hex
  if RegExMatch(str, "^\w+:/{0,2}", pr)
    StringTrimLeft, str, str, StrLen(pr)
  StringReplace, str, str, `%, `%25, All
  Loop
    if RegExMatch(str, "i)[^\w\.~%/:]", char)
      StringReplace, str, str, %char%, % "%" . SubStr(Asc(char),3), All
    else break
  SetFormat, Integer, %f%
  return, pr . str
}


F3::
image_search:
a = `%
old_clipboard := ClipboardAll
clipboard := url_encoding(clipboard)
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2" --force-wave-audio --incognito --new-window https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&as_q=%clipboard%, , Max
clipboard := old_clipboard
return
```

The change from %clipboard% to %A_LoopField% caused that https://www.google.com/imghp?tbm=isch&as_q= was opened when searching for abc. So I added the parsing Loop:

```
F3::
image_search:
a = `%
old_clipboard := ClipboardAll
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
  clipboard := url_encoding(clipboard)
  Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2" --force-wave-audio --incognito --new-window https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&as_q=%A_LoopField%, , Max
}
clipboard := old_clipboard
return
```

When I then opened

```
abc
123
```

the search queries were each opened in a new window. But these should only be opened in one new window. The goal is to exclude empty lines (also with whitespace) as well as whitespace before and after the search queries. Once this is done, url_encoding can be used to perform a correct search. In all these cases, the code just mentioned did not work. For example, if

```
 abc & def       


123 % 456
```

is in the clipboard, a new incognito window should show

```
abc & def
```

in tab 1 and

```
123 % 456
```

in tab 2.

Comment: You need a [parsing Loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm) in the hotkey command to retrieve each line of the clipboard as in this [example](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm#ExClipboard). Replace %clipboard% with %A_LoopField% in the Run command.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? I can see that this is not your code, so would I be correct in assuming you don't understand it at all? To do all lines, a simple loop would suffice.

Comment: The parsing Loop comes after `clipboard := url_encoding(clipboard)` otherwise the script parses the string "old_clipboard". I don't have Chrome, so I can't say exactly how it works. What message do you get if you add `MsgBox, %clipboard%` after `clipboard := url_encoding(clipboard)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url_encoding() added line breaks as

```
%D%A
```

because they were not excluded.

## Solution

```
url_encoding(str)
{
  f = %A_FormatInteger%
  SetFormat, Integer, Hex
  if RegExMatch(str, "^\w+:/{0,2}", pr)
    StringTrimLeft, str, str, StrLen(pr)
    StringReplace, str, str, `%, `%25, All
  Loop
    if RegExMatch(str, "i)[^\w\.~%/:\r\n]", char)
      StringReplace, str, str, %char%, % "%" . SubStr(Asc(char),3), All
    else break
  SetFormat, Integer, %f%
  return, pr . str
}


F3::
image_search:
old_clipboard := ClipboardAll
clipboard := RegExReplace(clipboard, "`am)^\s+")
clipboard := RegExReplace(clipboard, "`am)\s+$")
clipboard := url_encoding(clipboard)
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2" --force-wave-audio --incognito --new-window, , Max
Sleep, 1000
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
  Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2" --force-wave-audio --incognito https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&as_q=%A_LoopField%, , Max
  Sleep, 500
}
clipboard := old_clipboard
return
```